# How do I change link color in vuetify components without changing primary color?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How do I change link color without changing the primary color in theme for vuetify?
I tried this also:

```
$material-light: (
  "background": $telenor-color-background,
  "text": (
    "link": red,
  ),
);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: what about using a css filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Vuetify sets the anchors `<a>` color to the primary color of the theme. You can override this default with a custom color from a vuetify theme configuration.

From the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#customizing):

> By default, the theme service will use your application’s primary color for anchor tags. You can override this by adding an anchor property to the theme

```
const vuetify = new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        anchor: '#8c9eff', // defaults to 'primary', overrided to another color
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Do you know how to define the color for visited links? The docs doesn't say anything about it...